# Can i use attributes of element to create style rules?

Tags: html, css

I'm noot good in english, so the title may seem a bit odd.
I want to use css function attr() like this: 
[image: example]
I mean i have a container `<div>` and an inner `<div>` that i want to have width depending on data-width attribute. For example this would be great, but this doesnt work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-width="70%">
    </div
</div>
```

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}
.container div {
    width: attr(data-width);
    height: 100%;
}
```

Is there any noJS way to use attributes like that?

UPDATE: Guys convinced me that the JS is the only way to do this :)
That's not a big problem (but that's bad. CSS, why youre so illogical? Is the difference between `content:attr(data-width)` and `width: attr(data-width)` so big ?).

One of the guys had an idea to go through the all elements with jQuery.
That's ok, but it is very... local? Don't know how to say it in english.
Anyway, i remaked his code a little bit and here it is:

```
allowed = ['width','color','float'];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div').each(function (i, el) {
    var data = $(el).data(),style = '';
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(data)) {
      $.each(data, function (attr, value) {
        if (allowed.indexOf(attr) != - 1) {
          style += attr + ': ' + value + '; ';
        }
      })
      if (style.length != 0) {
        $(el).attr('style', style);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Idea is simple:
 1. We suppose that style we want to add to an element is the only one. I mean there are no scripts that will try to add some other styles,
 2. We create an array of allowed attribute names, we need to avoid using wrong names at the style attribute, for example `style="answerid: 30671428;"`,
 3. We go through each element, save its data attributes in an object, check if object is empty, and if not - check every attribute if it is allowed, create a string that contains all styles that we need, and - finally - add our style string to the element as the content of style attribute.

That's all, thanks everybody

Comment: Plain CSS can't use HTML attributes as values.

Comment: @j08691 not 100% true, works for content.

Comment: for what you describe what prevent you to change in your css width: attr(data-width); by width: 70%;

Comment: @epascarello - Perhaps, but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: `.container` should have many elements inside and every inner element should have its own width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not advise to use CSS alone since it will not allow you to do what you're looking for... instead use a scripting language (in my case jQuery) to accomplish this functionality for you like so: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/ev5xmazo/)

---

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var dataElem; // to store each data attribute we come accross
    jQuery('div').each(function(){ //loop through each div (can be changed to a class preferably)
        dataElem = jQuery(this); //get the current div
        if(dataElem.data('width')){ //make sure it exists before anything further
            dataElem.width(dataElem.data('width')); //set the element's width to the data attribute's value
            dataElem.css("background-color", "yellow");
        }
    });    
});
```

---

HTML

```
<p>The links with a data-width attribute gets a yellow background:</p>

<div>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
</div>
<div class="me" data-width="50"> <!-- change value to see the difference -->
    <a href="http://www.disney.com">disney.com</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>
</div>
```

---

Notes on the above:

1. [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: @lucifer63 care to explain how this is ''an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect?'' Quoting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Me too. But it wasn't lucifer64 who down voted us - you need at least 125 rep for that. Probably some troll.

Comment: I will reset that down vote for you because I do not think your answer was utterly useless (unlike the troll)... anyways it's really up to the OP at this point to decide what works best for them.

Comment: Yeah, seems like now it can be done only with JS. Well, ok) Your solution is good, but i think i need something more advanced, look at the update.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing data-width, use a class attribute. An html tag can have mutliple classes separated by spaces, so if you wanted to be very precise, you could set up as many classes as you need. For instance:

```
<div class="w70 h100">
</div>
```

Then in your css:

```
.w70{
    width: 70%;
}

.h100{
    height: 100%;
}
```

And so on.

Comment: A much easier way is to use javascript. Why are you against it?

Comment: I'm not againts JS, i just think i should write as less JS as possible. Of course i'll use JS if there will be no CSS way

Comment: There is a way involves minimal JS, but in my opinion it adds much more unnecessary complexity to the project. You would need to use a CSS pre-processor or compiler (for instance, Less CSS) that is basically able to generate CSS for you either at either run time or build time. I don't use Less though because I've never seen the necessity for it. But maybe it is worth looking into for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any noJS way to use attributes like that?

No, you cannot use CSS to set the width of the element to it's `data-width` attribute. CSS does not allow for this as [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) is only currently available for the CSS [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) property which is only available on css pseudo elements (`::before` and `::after`).

**How can you achieve this with as little javascript as possible?**

This is extremely easy to do using the native host provided [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

- Select the elements using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- Iterate the elements and apply the styles using [`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information#Modify_an_element_style) which can be retrieved from the `data-width` attribute using [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/q0m7wued/1/))

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#container div'), item, i;
for(i = 0; (item = items[i]); i++) item.style.width = item.dataset.width;
```